# jQuery - add navigation active class on parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to use jQuery to add an active class to an `<li>` only if it contains a nested 'child element' which has a particular class.

**Here is the rendered HTML code:**

```
<li class="primary-nav__item primary-nav__item--sub js-header-sub-link">
  <a class="primary-nav__link nav__link--sub js-header-sub-link-a" href="/collections/books">Books</a>
  <div class="nav__sub" id="sub-3">
    <div class="nav__sub-wrap">
      <ul class="nav__sub__items o-list-bare">
        <li class="nav__sub__item">
          <a class="nav__sub__link" href="#">I'm a sub-link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__sub__item nav__sub__item--sub js-header-sub-t-link nav__sub__item--active">
          <a class="nav__sub__link" href="#">I'm a sub-link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__sub__item">
          <a class="nav__sub__link" href="#">I'm a sub-link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

**Here's what I'd like to happen:**

The outermost `<li>` will get an additional class of `primary-nav__item--active` only if it contains a "child `<li>`" which has a class of `nav__sub__item--active`

**Here are the affected lines of code:**

[image]

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .closest() and search for '.primary-nav__item' then add your class.

Example:

```
$('.nav__sub__item--active').closest('.primary-nav__item').addClass('primary-nav__item--active')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

> [.addClass( function )](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/): function returning one or more space-separated class names to be added to the existing class name(s).

```js
$('.primary-nav__item').addClass(function(idx, className) {
    if ($(this).find('li.nav__sub__item--active').length > 0) {
        return 'active';
    }
})
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<li class="primary-nav__item primary-nav__item--sub js-header-sub-link">
    <a class="primary-nav__link nav__link--sub js-header-sub-link-a" href="/collections/books">Books</a>
    <div class="nav__sub" id="sub-3">
        <div class="nav__sub-wrap">
            <ul class="nav__sub__items o-list-bare">
                <li class="nav__sub__item">
                    <a class="nav__sub__link" href="#">I'm a sub-link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__sub__item nav__sub__item--sub js-header-sub-t-link nav__sub__item--active">
                    <a class="nav__sub__link" href="#">I'm a sub-link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__sub__item">
                    <a class="nav__sub__link" href="#">I'm a sub-link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `closest()` function is more efficient:

```js
$('.nav__sub__item--active').each(function() {
 $(this).closest('li.primary-nav__item').addClass('primary-nav__item--active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="primary-nav__item primary-nav__item--sub js-header-sub-link">
    <a class="primary-nav__link nav__link--sub js-header-sub-link-a" href="/collections/books">Books</a>
    <div class="nav__sub" id="sub-3">
      <div class="nav__sub-wrap">
        <ul class="nav__sub__items o-list-bare">
          <li class="nav__sub__item">
            <a class="nav__sub__link" href="#">I'm a sub-link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__sub__item nav__sub__item--sub js-header-sub-t-link nav__sub__item--active">
            <a class="nav__sub__link" href="#">I'm a sub-link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__sub__item nav__sub__item--active">
            <a class="nav__sub__link" href="#">I'm a sub-link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `closest` method.  It finds the first parent elemeent with a specific selector.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.nav__sub__item--active').closest('.primary-nav__item').addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<li class="primary-nav__item primary-nav__item--sub js-header-sub-link">
    <a class="primary-nav__link nav__link--sub js-header-sub-link-a" href="/collections/books">Books</a>
    <div class="nav__sub" id="sub-3">
        <div class="nav__sub-wrap">
            <ul class="nav__sub__items o-list-bare">
                <li class="nav__sub__item">
                    <a class="nav__sub__link" href="#">I'm a sub-link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__sub__item nav__sub__item--sub js-header-sub-t-link nav__sub__item--active">
                    <a class="nav__sub__link" href="#">I'm a sub-link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__sub__item">
                    <a class="nav__sub__link" href="#">I'm a sub-link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```